# selenium can't click on a specific button in instagram site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

hello I cant find a way to make selenium click on the ... button on a post webpage like : https://www.instagram.com/p/B9LHHvygBnz/

where the source code of the three dots on the corner of the post is like :

```
<div class="MEAGs">
    <button class="wpO6b " type="button">
        <div class="                   Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95       _4EzTm                                                                                                              " style="height: 24px; width: 24px;">
            <svg aria-label="More options" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="16" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="16">
                <circle clip-rule="evenodd" cx="8" cy="24" fill-rule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle> 
                <circle clip-rule="evenodd" cx="24" cy="24" fill-rule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle>
                <circle clip-rule="evenodd" cx="40" cy="24" fill-rule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle>
           </svg>
        </div>
    </button>
```

I have tried as many as ways I tought would work but selenium does not point to it for example I tried :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='MEAGs']")
```

and

```
posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='wpO6b ']")
```

and many outher ways (I've been working on this specific line of code for 2 days!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to click on the element that can receive the click, in this case on the `button`

xpath: `//div[@class='MEAGs']/button`

Comment: I don'y really know what a xpath is . can you give me the link ?

Comment: Check xpath syntax here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp or tutorial here https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/